# Flashing image to STM3220g-EVAL board using Trace 32

Tags: stm32, cortex-m, trace32, lauterbach

I have an STM3220g-EVAL board. It doesn't seem to have a preloaded image in it now, as it was used for other purposes.
When I power it on, the display is shown blank.

I dont have a STLINK/V2 hardware. I am using Trace32 and Lauterbach for flashing and debugging the code.

I created a simple C program, created an elf file by using arm-none-eabi-gcc toolchain, and was able to flash it into the STM3220g-EVAL board using a cmm script for stm32 provided in demo folder of Trace32.

What I require is to flash default image for STM3220g-eval using Trace32.
Can someone  provide me the link to get the boot image and cmm script to flash the same.

I tried the  demonstration builder platform and demonstration firmware provided in the following link 
http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/FM116/SC959/SS1532/PF250374

As they are providing hex file, I used Trace 32 command data.load.asciihex  to load the hex file. When I press go, am getting error( emulation poer fail).

Can somesome provide me the correct cmm script to flash the .hex file to the board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are trying to flash the "STM3220G-EVAL demonstration firmware" on your STM3220G-EVAL board.
So the hex-file you are talking about is "STM322xG_EVAL_FW_V1.2.0.hex", right?

This hex-file is in Intel HEX file format. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX)
To load a file in Intel HEX format, you should use `Data.LOAD.IntelHex`

So this is how to flash the file in your CPU:

1. Select your CPU with `SYStem.CPU STM32F207IG`
2. Connect to your CPU with `SYStem.Up`
3. Prepare flash-programming with `DO ~~/demo/arm/flash/stm32f2xx.cmm PREPAREONLY`
4. Arm flash programming with `FLASH.ReProgram ALL`
5. Load your Intel Hex file with `Data.LOAD.IntelHex STM322xG_EVAL_FW_V1.2.0.hex`
6. Finalize flash programming with `FLASH.ReProgram OFF` (This will start the actual programming.)

Answer (score 2):

The STM3220 comes with the STLink hardware built in via the USB port. See section 2.20 from [here](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/user_manual/DM00022972.pdf)

> Version 2 of the ST-LINK, called ST-LINK/V2, is embedded on the board.
>   This tool allows  onboard program loading and debugging of the STM32F
>   using the JTAG or SWD interface.  Third-party debug tools are also
>   supported by the JTAG (CN14) or Trace (CN13)  connectors. To
>   communicate with the embedded ST-LINK/V2, a specific driver needs to
>   be installed on  your PC. To download and install this driver, refer
>   to the software and development tools  page for the STM32F family
>   available on www.st.com (the install shield is called 
>   ST-LINK_V2_USBdriver.exe).